# Can Amazon DMS produce the state of a record before and after a change to Kafka?

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium, aws-dms

We're experimenting with Amazon DMS as an alternative to Debezium for producing SQL Server database changes to Kafka.  It's all going well, but there's one feature of Debezium that we're going to miss in DMS: the ability for the messages in Kafka to contain the state of the record both before and after then change was made.  Seems like with DMS, you only get the after version of the record, not the before.  Is there a setting for this somewhere?  I haven't been able to find any documentation indicating that there is but I figured I'd ask the Stack Overflow hivemind before I give up.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using beforeimage task settings to get the before image data record which will give you the before record values with a specified prefix and suffix to the column name. Add the below transformation rule in your task setting to get the desired output.

```
{
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "%",
        "table-name": "employees"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-before-image-columns",
      "before-image-def": {
        "column-prefix": "BI_",
        "column-suffix": "",
        "column-filter": "pk-only"
      }
    }
```